# How to scroll only inner elements only after reaching a certain height?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a screen, where there are a header, some content area and a table. I want to fix the screen when the text area crosses the header and scroll. The content which I mentioned in my plunker should be fixed and only the table, where the content will be hidden until he scrolls down again to that height, so the whole page is scrollable now.

I explored a lot, but I cannot achieve what I got.

CSS:

```
  body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
}
```

[Plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/8sLgt5ZsqNBbEXsNbYLc?p=preview).

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are looking for:

```css
.container {
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.scrollableContent {
  overflow-y: auto;
  max-height: 250px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="fixedContent">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer egestas elit a ante varius lacinia. Vivamus posuere pellentesque pulvinar. Aliquam erat volutpat. Etiam imperdiet tortor at augue dignissim vehicula. Praesent sit amet nulla efficitur,
      viverra arcu non, laoreet mauris. Maecenas eleifend tempus ligula accumsan venenatis. Morbi fermentum lectus at dictum commodo. Nullam commodo in nibh at dapibus. Maecenas sit amet nulla eget massa ultricies porttitor. Aenean blandit lacus a pellentesque
      blandit. Phasellus sit amet nisl id risus lobortis imperdiet convallis a augue. Proin nec lectus vel dui ultrices lacinia. In pretium justo nunc, at sodales augue dictum nec. Morbi quis libero molestie odio viverra porta. Integer varius elit sed
      tempor mollis. Curabitur finibus volutpat dictum. </p>
    <div style="height:150px;background-color:yelow">
      <h2>This needs to be fixed and below table region should be scrollable</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="scrollableContent">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer egestas elit a ante varius lacinia. Vivamus posuere pellentesque pulvinar.</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer egestas elit a ante varius lacinia. Vivamus posuere pellentesque pulvinar.</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer egestas elit a ante varius lacinia. Vivamus posuere pellentesque pulvinar.</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer egestas elit a ante varius lacinia. Vivamus posuere pellentesque pulvinar.</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer egestas elit a ante varius lacinia. Vivamus posuere pellentesque pulvinar.</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer egestas elit a ante varius lacinia. Vivamus posuere pellentesque pulvinar.</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer egestas elit a ante varius lacinia. Vivamus posuere pellentesque pulvinar.</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer egestas elit a ante varius lacinia. Vivamus posuere pellentesque pulvinar.</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer egestas elit a ante varius lacinia. Vivamus posuere pellentesque pulvinar.</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer egestas elit a ante varius lacinia. Vivamus posuere pellentesque pulvinar.</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer egestas elit a ante varius lacinia. Vivamus posuere pellentesque pulvinar.</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer egestas elit a ante varius lacinia. Vivamus posuere pellentesque pulvinar.</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer egestas elit a ante varius lacinia. Vivamus posuere pellentesque pulvinar.</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer egestas elit a ante varius lacinia. Vivamus posuere pellentesque pulvinar.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: exactly..but can I avoid two scrollbars

Comment: @SibiRaj just set `overflow:hidden;` to the table

Comment: yes you can, but only when the whole content matches the excat height of the browser. You have to make it responsive with: body,html { height: 100% } .container { height: 100% } .fixedContent { height: calc(100% - 350px); }

Comment: I ll try that@DominikNoll

Comment: I need that h2 part to be fixed when it reaches the top

Comment: Maybe this can help you: [Scroll-Fix-Content](https://css-tricks.com/scroll-fix-content/)

Comment: Also this gets affected when body height decreases

Answer (score 0):

```js
// Code goes here

$(function(){
  
  
  
var distance = $('.fixed').offset().top;

$(window).on("scroll", function() {
 
    if ( $(window).scrollTop() >= distance - 85 ) {
      $("body").css("overflow","hidden");
      $(".table-responsive").css("overflow","auto");
    }
    else
    {
       
    }
});

$(".table-responsive").on("scroll", function() {
 
  if($(this).scrollTop() === 0)
  {
    $("body").css("overflow","auto");
    $(".table-responsive").css("overflow","hidden");
  }
});


});
```

```css
/* Styles go here */

html {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

.header {
  height: 60px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 100;
  background: white;
}

.content {
  position: absolute;
  top: 60px;
  height: 500px;
}

body {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow:hidden;
}

.table-responsive
{
  height:100vh;
  overflow:auto;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
   <script data-require="jquery" data-semver="3.0.0" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="header">Head</div>
  <div class="content">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 
      tempor mollis. Curabitur finibus volutpat dictum. </p>
    <div class="fixed" style="height:50px;background-color:yelow">
      <h2>This needs to be fixed and below table region should be scrollable</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="table-responsive">
      <table class="table">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>
              [HEADER]
            </th>
            <th>
              [HEADER]
            </th>
            <th>
              [HEADER]
            </th>
            <th>
              [HEADER]
            </th>
            <th>
              [HEADER]
            </th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

try with giving body fix view port height with  hidden overflow and the inner div view port height with overflow

```
body {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow:hidden;
}

.table-responsive
{
  height:100vh;
  overflow:auto;
}
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/eHpVkh2q921EDmWwUMNz?p=preview

Comment: yeah,but I need to scroll hide the paragraph and then the scroll should happen to the table content. Is it possible

Comment: @SibiRaj updated the answer as per your requirement. I am using jquery here , let me know if you need it in plain javascript only

Answer (score 0):

see my solution

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <script src="script.js"></script>
<style>
  .table-responsive{
  
    overflow: auto;
    max-height: 100px;
  }
  </style>
  
  </head>

  
<body>
  <div class="header">Head</div>
  <div class="content">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer egestas elit a ante varius lacinia. Vivamus posuere pellentesque pulvinar. Aliquam erat volutpat. Etiam imperdiet tortor at augue dignissim vehicula. Praesent sit amet nulla efficitur,
      viverra arcu non, laoreet mauris. Maecenas eleifend tempus ligula accumsan venenatis. Morbi fermentum lectus at dictum commodo. Nullam commodo in nibh at dapibus. Maecenas sit amet nulla eget massa ultricies porttitor. Aenean blandit lacus a pellentesque
      blandit. Phasellus sit amet nisl id risus lobortis imperdiet convallis a augue. Proin nec lectus vel dui ultrices lacinia. In pretium justo nunc, at sodales augue dictum nec. Morbi quis libero molestie odio viverra porta. Integer varius elit sed
      tempor mollis. Curabitur finibus volutpat dictum. </p>
    <div style="height:150px;background-color:yelow">
      <h2>This needs to be fixed and below table region should be scrollable</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="table-responsive">
      <table class="table">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>
              [HEADER]
            </th>
            <th>
              [HEADER]
            </th>
            <th>
              [HEADER]
            </th>
            <th>
              [HEADER]
            </th>
            <th>
              [HEADER]
            </th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
            <td>
              [CONTENT]
            </td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I 'll try this one

Comment: can You Post the CSS or plunker. This is what I am looking for.

Comment: @SibiRaj see head tag  css kept in style tag

Comment: @SibiRaj as requested plunker https://plnkr.co/edit/Gfb98DnRq32jTHltRDbn?p=preview

Comment: but what I wanted is that h2 part should not go beyond the header. it should scroll up to the header only

Comment: sorry My mistake I didn't see properly, thanks @pawan kotak

Comment: I still have only one doubt left. Can I get rid of two scrollbars. I tried overflow:hidden, but the scroll never works

Comment: One you will get for table because we have fixed the height and other if your page content is more then page height.. Can you please share the screen shot